# tweepy IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, split, tweepy

This could be a super stupid mistake, but I just cant see what's wrong.

```
class listener(tweepy.streaming.StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        tweet = data.split(',"text":"')[1].split('","source')[0]
        screen_name = data.split(',"screen_name":"')[1].split('","location":')[0]
        print tweet
        print data
        return True
    def on_error(self, status):
        print status

def main():
    twitterStream = tweepy.Stream(auth, listener()) 
    twitterStream.userstream()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Rex\702_EH\new 1.py", line 35, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Rex\702_EH\new 1.py", line 32, in main
    twitterStream.userstream()
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\tweepy\streaming.py", line 394, in userstream
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\tweepy\streaming.py", line 361, in _start
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\tweepy\streaming.py", line 294, in _run
IndexError: list index out of range
```

can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tweets you get are in a JSON format, you should take advantage of that rather than trying to parse them as plain text. The attributes will be a lot easier to extract, and your code will also be much more readable.

```
class listener(tweepy.streaming.StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):

        decoded = json.loads(data)

        tweet = decoded['text']
        screen_name = decoded['user']['screen_name']
        print tweet
        print data
        return True
    def on_error(self, status):
        print status

def main():
    twitterStream = tweepy.Stream(auth, listener()) 
    twitterStream.userstream()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

As a sidenote, I suggest you switch to Python3, dealing with Unicode in Python2 can be quite nightmarish.

Comment: Thx for answering,but this code shows: KeyError: 'text'. any further tips?

Comment: Also thx for your suggestion, but for this one, it might be too late to switch.

Answer (score 0):

The output of Tweepy response is JSON. Because JSON is an standard in intra-communicating between applications you should follow this standard by using json lib in python. So you need to load Tweepy response like this:

```
tweet = json.loads(data)
username = tweet[user][screeen_name]
language = tweet[user][lang]
......
.....
```

Comment: Thx for answering, but here shows another error: NameError: global name 'user' is not defined

Comment: It's just an example @Rex , just watch the tweet variable and named the JSON key that you want it's value.